# Saving Recorded shows from FMS in a folder under public_html

Tags: flash-media-server

This must be a newbie question. I have found info on how to change the folder that FMS is saving the recorded videos in it.. but never seen or found how to make this folder to be one under the public_html folder.

For example, I am using Meesum:  Flash Media Interactive Server Enterprise v4 and i see it is saving the recorded shows to:

```
/opt/adobe/fms/applications/mmm_play/streams
```

But this folder is above the `public_html` folder.. I want to save them instead to the folder videos under `public_html`:

```
/home/mmm/public_html/videos
```

But when I change this in all the application.xml files, it still keeps saving them to the first path not to the new one.. even if i restart the FMS server...

Am i putting the path correct? any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlink so your /home/mmm/public_html/videos can point to /opt/adobe/fms/applications/mmm_play/streams.